# Using conditional to generate new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   portion  used
0        1   1.0
1        2   0.3
2        3   0.0
3        4   0.8
```

I'd like to create a new column based on the `used` column, so that the `df` looks like this:

```
   portion  used    alert
0        1   1.0     Full
1        2   0.3  Partial
2        3   0.0    Empty
3        4   0.8  Partial
```

- Create a new `alert` column based on
- If `used` is `1.0`, `alert` should be `Full`.
- If `used` is `0.0`, `alert` should be `Empty`.
- Otherwise, `alert` should be `Partial`.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 50):

You can define a function which returns your different states "Full", "Partial", "Empty", etc and then use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply the function to each row. Note that you have to pass the keyword argument `axis=1` to ensure that it applies the function to rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

def alert(row):
  if row['used'] == 1.0:
    return 'Full'
  elif row['used'] == 0.0:
    return 'Empty'
  elif 0.0 < row['used'] < 1.0:
    return 'Partial'
  else:
    return 'Undefined'

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'portion':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'used':[1.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.8]})

df['alert'] = df.apply(alert, axis=1)

#    portion  used    alert
# 0        1   1.0     Full
# 1        2   0.3  Partial
# 2        3   0.0    Empty
# 3        4   0.8  Partial
```

Comment: Great example. To make the code a little bit clearer (and since you are using `axis=1`), you could re-name the parameter `c` to `row`, that way is really obvious that you have access to all values of the row in the function.

Answer (score 45):

Alternatively you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'portion':np.arange(10000), 'used':np.random.rand(10000)})

%%timeit
df.loc[df['used'] == 1.0, 'alert'] = 'Full'
df.loc[df['used'] == 0.0, 'alert'] = 'Empty'
df.loc[(df['used'] >0.0) & (df['used'] < 1.0), 'alert'] = 'Partial'
```

Which gives the same output but runs about 100 times faster on 10000 rows:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
```

Then using apply:

```
%timeit df['alert'] = df.apply(alert, axis=1)

1 loops, best of 3: 287 ms per loop
```

I guess the choice depends on how big is your dataframe.

Comment: Question on the %timeit: if the first did 100 loops @2.91 seconds, does that mean total time is 291 ms, slightly longer than the 287ms time for the alert function to complete the 1 loop?

Comment: 1 loop in this case is running 3 lines of code after `%%timeit`. Number of loops (100 in this case) are chosen automatically by the `timeit` program to give more robust measure within some sensible "timeout" (i.e. if running 1 loop is longer than this "timeout" there will be only 1 loop, like in case of "using apply"). Results of `timeit` should be compared on a "per 1 loop" basis. That's why there is "runs about 100 times faster" phrase: 1 loop that took 2.91 ms is about 100 times faster than 1 loop that took 287 ms.

Answer (score 21):

Use `np.where`, is usually fast

```
In [845]: df['alert'] = np.where(df.used == 1, 'Full', 
                                 np.where(df.used == 0, 'Empty', 'Partial'))

In [846]: df
Out[846]:
   portion  used    alert
0        1   1.0     Full
1        2   0.3  Partial
2        3   0.0    Empty
3        4   0.8  Partial
```

---

<sub>Timings</sub>

```
In [848]: df.shape
Out[848]: (100000, 3)

In [849]: %timeit df['alert'] = np.where(df.used == 1, 'Full', np.where(df.used == 0, 'Empty', 'Partial'))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.17 ms per loop

In [850]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[df['used'] == 1.0, 'alert'] = 'Full'
     ...: df.loc[df['used'] == 0.0, 'alert'] = 'Empty'
     ...: df.loc[(df['used'] >0.0) & (df['used'] < 1.0), 'alert'] = 'Partial'
     ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ms per loop

In [851]: %timeit df['alert'] = df.apply(alert, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.79 s per loop
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if your condition is not too complex.

Answer (score 6):

### Use [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for >2 conditions

Given >2 conditions like OP's example, [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is much cleaner than nesting multiple levels of [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (and is just as fast).

- Either define the conditions/choices as two lists (paired element-wise) with an optional default value ("else" case):

  ```
  conditions = [
      df.used.eq(0),
      df.used.eq(1),
  ]
  choices = [
      'Empty',
      'Full',
  ]
  df['alert'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Partial')
  ```
- Or define the conditions/choices as a dictionary for maintainability (easier to keep them paired properly when making additions/revisions):

  ```
  conditions = {
      'Empty': df.used.eq(0),
      'Full': df.used.eq(1),
  }
  df['alert'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default='Partial')
  ```

---

### [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is very fast

Timings with 5 conditions (full, high, medium, low, empty):

[image: timings with 5 conditions]

<sup>*`df = pd.DataFrame({'used': np.random.randint(10 + 1, size=10)}).div(10)`*</sup>

Comment: Do you have the code or example of how you created this chart for this answer? I'd love to show this to some folks.

Comment: That's a [perfplot](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/0.2.3/) @scarebear

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment so making a new answer: Improving on Ffisegydd's approach, you can use a dictionary and the `dict.get()` method to make the function to pass in to `.apply()` easier to manage:

```
import pandas as pd

def alert(c):
    mapping = {1.0: 'Full', 0.0: 'Empty'}
    return mapping.get(c['used'], 'Partial')

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'portion':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'used':[1.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.8]})

df['alert'] = df.apply(alert, axis=1)
```

Depending on the use case, you might like to define the dict outside of the function definition as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['TaxStatus'] = np.where(df.Public == 1, True, np.where(df.Public == 2, False))
```

This would appear to work, except for the ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given