# Pandas Date Conditional Calculation

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a column in Pandas based off of a conditional statement that calculates time between two events.  I was able to work out the day calculation but when plugged into my conditional statement:

```
def defect_age(df):
    if df['Status'] == 'R':
        return (pd.to_datetime(df['resolved_on'], errors='coerce') 
            - pd.to_datetime(df['submitted_on'])) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    else:
        return 'null'
```

And then later called by the column:

```
group_df['Age'] = group_df.apply(defect_age(group_df), axis=0)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried to base mine on the question asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041724/using-conditional-to-generate-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe)... But I am not having much success. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this definition of `defect_age`

```
def defect_age(df):
    resolved = pd.to_datetime(df.resolved_on, errors='coerce')
    submitted = pd.to_datetime(df.submitted_on)
    r = (resolved - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    return np.where(df.Status == 'R', r, np.nan)
```

The error was coming from `if df['Status'] == 'R'`

This would have been a series of boolean values and not a single boolean value that `if` needs.  You still want to run this over the whole series at once.  I hope I've given you something that does the trick.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks.  Your answer is exactly what I was trying to figure out.  I've got a bunch more statuses that I'm gonna add now :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :

```
group_df['Age'] = group_df.apply(lambda row:defect_age(row), axis=1)
```

This is because you want to apply the function to each row not to the whole dataframe at once.

`df['Status'] == 'R'` will give a list of booleans if applied on a dataframe and u cant put a list of booleans in an if expression