# how to create a row_number based on some conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame like this:

```
   Clinic Number        date
0              1  2015-05-05
1              1  2015-05-05
2              1  2016-01-01
3              2  2015-05-05
4              2  2016-05-05
5              3  2017-05-05
6              3  2017-05-05
```

I want to create a new column and fill it out based on some conditions. so the new data frame should be like this:

```
   Clinic Number    date      row_number
0              1  2015-05-05    1
1              1  2015-05-05    1
2              1  2016-01-01    2
3              2  2015-05-05    3
4              2  2016-05-05    4
5              3  2017-05-05    5
6              3  2017-05-05    5
```

what is the rule for putting entries inside new column:
where Clinic Number and date is the same they will get same numbers, if it changes it will increases.

For example here `1  2015-05-05` has two rows which have same `Clinic Number and date` so they all get `1`. the next row have Clinic Number=1 but the date is not the same as previous rows so it will get `2`.
where `Clinic Number=2` there is no row with Clinic Number=2 and the same date so it got `3` and the next row is `4`...

till now I have tried something like this:

```
def createnumber(x):
    x['row_number'] = i

d['row_number']= pd1.groupby(['Clinic Number','date']).apply(createnumber)
```

but I do not know how to implement this function.

I appreciate if you can help me with this:)
Also I have looked at links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041724/using-conditional-to-generate-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe) but they are not dynamic (i mean here the row number should be increased based on some conditions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `groupby`, you could just do something like this, naming your conditions seperately. So if the date shifts OR the clinic number changes, you return `True`, and then get the `cumsum` of those `True` values:

```
df['row_number'] = (df.date.ne(df.date.shift()) | df['Clinic Number'].ne(df['Clinic Number'].shift())).cumsum()


>>> df
   Clinic Number        date  row_number
0              1  2015-05-05           1
1              1  2015-05-05           1
2              1  2016-01-01           2
3              2  2015-05-05           3
4              2  2016-05-05           4
5              3  2017-05-05           5
```

You'll need to make sure your dataframe is sorted by `Clinic Number` and `Date` first (you could do `df.sort_values(['Clinic Number', 'date'], inplace=True)` if it's not sorted already)

Comment: do you have any idea of this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458599/how-to-append-files-efficiently-based-on-some-conditions Actually the way Im going to do is not efficient. Id appreciate it if you have time only have a quick look