# Is there a way to populate a column based on if the values of another column falls withing a range of numbers in python?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I'm working on a data table and I need to create a new column based on which of the classes the value of another column falls in.

This is the original table:

```
ID  sequence
AJ8    2
FT7    3
JU4    5
ER2    3
LI5    2
FR2    7
WS1    8
UG4    9
```

The ranges are 2, 3, 4, 6: first; 1,5,0: second; and 7,8, 9: third.

I created the variables

```
first  = ['2', '3', '4', '6']
second = ['1', '5', '0']
third  = ['7', '8', '9']
```

I want to get the following table

```
ID  sequence    code
AJ8    2        FIRST
FT7    3        FIRST
JU4    5        SECOND
ER2    3        FIRST
LI5    2        FIRST
FR2    7        THIRD
WS1    8        THIRD
UG4    9        THIRD
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using a pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes I am using pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function that conditionally returns the value you want.

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ['AJ8', 'FT7', 'JU4', 'ER2', 'LI5', 'FR2', 'WS1', 'UG4']
values = [2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(keys, values)), columns =['key', 'value'])

def get_new_column(df):
    if df['value'] in [2, 3, 4, 6]:
        return 'first'
    elif df['value'] in [1, 5, 0]:
        return 'second'
    elif df['value'] in [7, 8, 9]:
        return 'third'
    else:
        return ''

df['new'] = df.apply(get_new_column, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   key  value     new
0  AJ8      2   first
1  FT7      3   first
2  JU4      5  second
3  ER2      3   first
4  LI5      2   first
5  FR2      7   third
6  WS1      8   third
7  UG4      9   third
```

Here are more [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27041889/3923163).