# If-else ValueError The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, valueerror

I am trying to fill the missing values using if-else condition but getting the value error 
How can I resolve? 
I read another similar post but couldn't apply to my problem

I have tried if-else (value error) and also, iterate through indexing using for loop

When using for loop, it runs all rows through only if statement, and not going to else

Only if else statement(Value error)

```
if data['Waiting Time'] > 0:
    data['Existing_Date'].fillna(data['New_time'],inplace=True) #if wait_time > 0         
else:
    data['Existing_Date'].fillna(data['Actual Date'],inplace=True) #if wait_time > 0
```

Using For-loop indexing(only running if statement )

```
for i in data.index:
    if data['Waiting Time'].iloc[i] > 0:
        data['Existing_Date'].fillna(data['New_time'],inplace=True) #if wait_time > 0    
    else:
        data['Existing_Date'].fillna(data['Actual Date'],inplace=True) #if wait_time = 0
```

With if only statement Value error

with for loop: only result in if statement, not going to else statement

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Would you mind sharing the TraceBack for the error ?

Comment: Can you give a small example of what the `data` looks like before, and how it should change after?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel data['Exisitng_Date'] column has missing value I want to fill in with New_time column if df (waiting time - equal rows has integers) is greater than 0 else with Actual Date coumn type is Datetime64

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041724/using-conditional-to-generate-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe help?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the first code does not enter `else:` is because you are testing the entire dataframe, and it will return `True` for existence. You are not actually querying the values that meet the condition.

The reason why you are getting the `ValueError` is because you are testing multiple values at the same time (the entire array of values), in which case you potentially get multiple `True` and multiple `False`.

I would not recommend looping through a `dataframe` like you did. You can use `loc` and some logic. It really depends on the exact output you are looking for, but likely `pandas` have already tools for your use without the need to iterate through the `dataframe`

```py
data.loc[data['Waiting Time'] > 0,'Existing_Date'].fillna(data['New_time'],inplace=True)
data.loc[data['Waiting Time'] <= 0,'Existing_Date'].fillna(data['Actual Date'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tried this, it is showing me 'NaT' values in missing fields after running

Comment: Is your data as `datetime` or as `str` ? Per the docs: _For datetime64[ns] types, NaT represents missing values. This is a pseudo-native sentinel value that can be represented by NumPy in a singular dtype (datetime64[ns]). pandas objects provide compatibility between NaT and NaN._