# Creating Loyalty labels for a user using conditions on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with a sample attached. I want to give loyalty labels for all the users in my dataframe.

The labels and their conditions are:

- `first_time_visitor` - any user with session = 0 (see the first line in loyalty column)
- `frequent_visitor` - any user with session > 0 and count_session_products > 0
- `first_time_customer` - first time checkout:confirmation appears in the type column
- `repeat_customer` - second time of checkout:confirmation appears in the type column
- `loyal_customer` - third time of checkout:confirmation appears in the type column

I am having trouble calculating `first_time_customer`, `repeat_customer` and `loyal_customer` labels.

I have had a couple of ideas only, one being to use `first_valid_index()` or `argmax()` to find the index and somehow use that in a condition to create the `first_time_customer` label.

```
(df_customer_1.type.values == 'checkout:confirmation').argmax()
df_customer_1[df_customer_1.type == 'checkout:confirmation'].first_valid_index()
```

But I am not sure how to implement these conditions.

In the end I would like the loyalty column in the picture to look like:

```
first_time_visitor
frequent_visitor
first_time_customer
repeat_customer
frequent_visitor
loyal_customer
```

Can anyone guide me as to how I can achieve this? I do not have any code to show for it so far therefore you would probably have to come up with something. We can try both pandas or a typical pythonic way.

This is what I have so far, sample from the data:

```
data = {
'user_id': [
    '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX',
    '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX'
],
'timestamp': [
    1612139269, 1612139665, 1612139579,
    1612141096, 1612143046, 1612143729
],
'type': ['productDetails', 'productDetails', 'checkout:confirmation', 'checkout:confirmation', 'productList', 'checkout:confirmation'],
'session': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
'count_session_products': [4, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2],
'loyalty' : [0,0,0,0,0,0]}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
test_df
```

which gives me:

| user_id | timestamp | type | session | prods | loyalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139269 | productDetails | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139665 | productDetails | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139579 | checkout:confirmation | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612141096 | checkout:confirmation | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143046 | productList | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143729 | checkout:confirmation | 5 | 2 | 0 |

First condition for frequent_visiotr and first_time_visitor:

```
test_df['loyalty'] = np.where((test_df['session'] > 0) & ((test_df['type'] != 'checkout:confirmation')), 'frequent_visitor', None)
test_df.loc[test_df['session'] == 0, 'loyalty'] = 'first_time_visitor'
```

which gives me:

| user_id | timestamp | type | session | prods | loyalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139269 | productDetails | 0 | 4 | first_time_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139665 | productDetails | 1 | 1 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139579 | checkout:confirmation | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612141096 | checkout:confirmation | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143046 | productList | 4 | 2 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143729 | checkout:confirmation | 5 | 2 | 0 |

Now this is where I am stuck, I need conditions for first_time_customer, repeat_customer and loyal_customer. The rules for these conditions are described above. I would like the end dataframe to look like this:

| user_id | timestamp | type | session | prods | loyalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139269 | productDetails | 0 | 4 | first_time_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139665 | productDetails | 1 | 1 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139579 | checkout:confirmation | 2 | 0 | first_time_customer |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612141096 | checkout:confirmation | 3 | 4 | repeat_customer |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143046 | productList | 4 | 2 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143729 | checkout:confirmation | 5 | 2 | loyal_customer |

[image]

Comment: Pandas makes this kind of thing very simple. Your question would be much better written if you gave Pandas a try and described where you got stuck. I suggest you search for some question using search terms "pandas add column based on condition". For example, here's a good question that offers a nice example of where to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041724/using-conditional-to-generate-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the suggestion. Can you have a look at the question now? Hopefully it will help you understand the problem better now :)

Comment: This is a well written question now, much more specific, including code and a simplified example. I would add a separate column for each condition (if you want you can add a final column combining all conditions, but only after you have a column for each specific condition). The first time customer column, for example, would be simply `is_new_customer = df['session'] == 0` which returns a `pd.Series` object which you can then just add to the dataframe with `df['is_new_cusotmer'] = is_new_customer`. Now you have a column of True|False values to identify new customers.

Comment: This question also covers adding columns to a dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-dataframe

Comment: Here's another useful reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a mapping exercise so I'll perform a couple a let you do the rest.

```
def determine_loyalty(data: Series) -> str:
  if data["session"] == 0:
    return "first_time_visitor"
  elif data["session"] > 0 and data["count_session_products"] > 0:
    return "frequent_visitor"


df = DataFrame([{session:0,count_session_products:0},{session:2,count_session_products:6}]) # your dataframe
df["loyalty"] = df.apply(lambda x: determine_loyalty(x))
```

This will give you:

```
print(df)
   session  count_session_products             loyalty
0        0                       0  first_time_visitor
1        2                       6    frequent_visitor
```

Now if you only want first time customers you can do:

```
first_time_customers: DataFrame = df[df["loyalty"] == "first_time_visitor"]
```

String filtering is bound to be slower than int/bool comparisons so I'd strongly suggest you give the dataframes levels that your application knows the meaning of in the model. For example:

```
class LoyaltyLevels(Enum):
    FIRST_TIME_VISITOR=1
    FREQUENT_VISITOR=2



# change determine_loyalty to give integer values instead
def determine_loyalty(data: Series) -> str:
  if data["session"] == 0:
    return LoyaltyLevels.FIRST_TIME_VISITOR.value
  elif data["session"] > 0 and data["count_session_products"] > 0:
    return LoyaltyLevels.FREQUENT_VISITOR.value


# now we can filter using the integer value

first_time = df[df["loyalty"] == LoyaltyLevels.FIRST_TIME_VISITOR.value]
```

Comment: I understand this and have the conditions for first_time_visitor and frequent_visitor already created, but the problem is how do I apply the filter for the first_time_customer label? What would the condition be for it?

Comment: @Salaaned answered above